# CSS fix for IE on menù with flex

Tags: css, internet-explorer-11

Can someone help me fix this menu on IE11 that works without problems on chrome?

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xur354j8/)

```
$(".menu > ul > li").hover(function (e) {
        $(this).children("ul").stop(true, false).fadeToggle(150);
        if ($(this).children("ul").css('display') == "block") { $(this).children("ul").css('display', 'flex'); }
        e.preventDefault();
});
```

`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet**. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website/example doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Answer (score 0):

Try to add the width property for the inner ul container.

Change the following code:

```
            .menu > ul > li > ul {
                position: absolute;
                z-index: 99;
                display: none;
                top: 106%;
                z-index: 1000;
                padding: 5px 0;
                font-size: 14px;
                text-align: left;
                list-style: none;
                background-color: #fff;
                -webkit-background-clip: padding-box;
                background-clip: padding-box;
                -webkit-box-shadow: 0 6px 12px rgba(0,0,0,.175);
                box-shadow: 0 6px 12px rgba(0,0,0,.175);
                right: -10px;
            }
```

to (add width property):

```
            .menu > ul > li > ul {
                position: absolute;
                z-index: 99;
                display: none;
                top: 106%;
                z-index: 1000;
                padding: 5px 0;
                font-size: 14px;
                text-align: left;
                list-style: none;
                background-color: #fff;
                -webkit-background-clip: padding-box;
                background-clip: padding-box;
                -webkit-box-shadow: 0 6px 12px rgba(0,0,0,.175);
                box-shadow: 0 6px 12px rgba(0,0,0,.175);
                right: -10px;
                width:500px;
            }
```

The result in the IE browser as below:

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer
the problem is that I can't put a fixed size. it must adapt to the number of elements.
I solved it by setting it via script to hover

Comment: It's OK, the good news is you solved the problem, cheers ^-^.

Answer (score 0):

I can't put a fixed size. it must adapt to the number of elements.

I solved it by setting it via script to hover

```
$(".menu > ul > li").hover(function (e) {
        $(this).children("ul").stop(true, false).fadeToggle(150);
        if ($(this).children("ul").css('display') == "block") { 
            $(this).children("ul").css('display', 'flex'); 
          $(this).children("ul").width(160*$(this).children("ul").children().length);
        }
        e.preventDefault();
});
```